# Disable image attachment resize dialog for new emails in Thunderbird

Tags: windows-7, images, thunderbird, attachments

I think I can manage the size and bandwidth of the images I'm sending via emails myself, but any time a large enough image is attached to a new email, e.g. via Windows Explorer right-clicking an image → Send as Email, Thunderbird asks me if I want to resize the image.

[image: image resize dialog]

It has caused more trouble than benefit in the past, e.g. instructing some users to send some important scans via email, which would then send them in the downscaled size instead of the original one.

How do you disable this option in Thunderbird? My version is 11, but this option exists for previous versions, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK It's not Thunderbird that comes up with this resize image dialog, but Windows Explorer itself, so that Thunderbird is really not to blame for this "feature" of Windows.

The only way I know to disable this dialog is to make Windows forget that the
file-type is that of an image (for example .jpg), because
as long as it remains for Explorer an image-type
it will always come up with this "helpful" dialog.
Of course, this change might have undesirable side-effects, but it is easy to undo.

- Run regedit and navigate to the key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.jpg`.
- Backup the key by right-click and Export to a .reg file.
- In the right-pane, you will see and item called `PerceivedType` with the value of `image`
- Double-click `PerceivedType` and assign it a blank value.
- Repeat as required for other image types such as .gif.
- Close regedit.
- Reboot or logout+login.

In case of undesirable side-effects, return the value of `PerceivedType` to `image`
either manually or by double-click on the saved .reg file.

It is also suggested to take a system restore snapshot before doing any registry work.

Source: [Microsoft article KB 883393](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/883393).